How to Automatically Recognize Type Definitions in Nuxt.js Project Without Explicit Imports in VSCode?
I'm working on a Nuxt.js project with TypeScript and I'm encountering issues with VSCode not recognizing my type definitions automatically. I want to avoid explicitly importing types in every file. Here is my setup and the problem I'm facing:
Project Setup
I have the following tsconfig.json configuration:
{
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["./types/**/*.d.ts"]
}

Problem
Currently, I have to manually import types in each file, like this:
import { IMongoCase } from "~/types";

I would like to configure my project so that VSCode automatically recognizes the types without needing to import them explicitly in every file.
Attempts to Solve
I've tried the following:

Ensured that the types folder is correctly placed and that the .d.ts files are properly defined.
Restarted VSCode and its TypeScript server.
Verified that the paths and baseUrl options are set correctly in tsconfig.json.

Desired Outcome
I want to be able to use the types directly in my code without importing them, like so:
const caseExample: IMongoCase = { ... };

Additional Context

VSCode Version: 1.89.1
TypeScript Version: 5.4.5
Nuxt.js Version: 3.11.2

Question
How can I configure my project so that VSCode recognizes the type definitions automatically, without requiring explicit imports in each file? What changes do I need to make to my tsconfig.json or any other configuration to achieve this?

Firstly, you don't need to modify tsconfig.json. All the ts files are included by default. "include": ["./types/**/*.d.ts"] is not needed. You can inspect the config in ~/.nuxt/tsconfig.json.
You can add types to the global namespace to achieve your goal.
// ~/types/my-types.d.ts
declare global {
  interface IMongoCase {
    test: string
  }
}

// tell TypeScript that this file is a module
export {}


Is there a way to declare global for like 100 interfaces without wrapping them in a declare global {}? Or I need it to do it for every of my d.ts files? I want to use the index.d.ts for the  /// <reference path="..." /> strategy
